# Is it possible to pass a COBOL File Descriptor to another program

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, jcl

Can I pass a File Control FD entry in main COBOL code into a procedure?

If yes, What do I need to pass when calling the procedure from the main COBOL program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `EXTERNAL` keyword in the `FD`, allows the same file to be accessed by multiple programs within the run unit. Rather than "passing" the `FD`, the run time points the separate programs to the same `FD`.

The `SELECT` and `FD` must describe the same file.

In the following, `pgm-main` opens and closes the file, `pgm-1` writes to the file, and `pgm-2` reads the file.

```
   program-id. pgm-main.
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select f assign "f.dat"
           organization sequential
       .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd f external.
   1 f-rec pic 99.
   procedure division.
       open output f
       call "pgm-1"
       close f
       open input f
       call "pgm-2"
       close f
       goback
       .
   end program pgm-main.

   program-id. pgm-1.
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select f assign "f.dat"
           organization sequential
       .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd f external.
   1 f-rec pic 99.
   working-storage section.
   1 x comp pic 99.
   procedure division.
       perform varying x from 1 by 1
       until x > 5
           move x to f-rec
           write f-rec
       end-perform
       goback
       .
   end program pgm-1.

   program-id. pgm-2.
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select f assign "f.dat"
           organization sequential
       .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd f external.
   1 f-rec pic 99.
   working-storage section.
   1 pic x value "0".
     88 eof value "1".
   procedure division.
       perform until eof
           read f
           end
               set eof to true
           not end
               display f-rec
           end-read
       end-perform
       goback
       .
   end program pgm-2.
```

Output:

```
01
02
03
04
05
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach rather than a direct answer to the question. Its an approach Cobol programmers may across and should know about.
I added for information purposes.

---

An alternative approach to passing a File-Control around is to use a `File-Driver` or `File-Interface` module that does the Reading/Writing of the file. The individual applications programs call this program, this approach works best if a file is used in multiple places.

There are advantages of a `File-Driver` include

- You can make the file-record-area in the Linkage much larger than file-record size.
  The file might have a 50 byte record with 20 byte filler, you could make the *File-Record-Linkage* area 500 bytes. That may reduce maintenance in the future.
- Typically Control records / header / footer records can be written / checked in the `File-Driver` program. The application programs do not need to know about any control records. At one site I needed to add Header/Footer and file validation to an existing file. All I needed to was change `Code Generation parameters`, regenerate the `File-Driver` and some basic testing. No program change was needed
- `File-Drivers` are almost identical. You can

  - Store the bulk of the *Working Storage* and *Code* in Copybooks and use **Copy replacing**.
  - Use Code generation
  - Standard Copy modify
- File drivers can be tested separately from the calling program. That is handy when you are using file validation.